# viewForAnnotation method never called

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

I have implemented my `MKMapViewDelegate`, but for some reason my `viewForAnnotation` method is never called.

I can confirm that annotations are displayed on the MapView.

I've added an `NSLog()` to my method and the logging statement is never printed.

I know my class is definitely the `MKMapViewDelegate` because `NSLog()` statements in other `MKMapViewDelegate` methods are printed out.

I am also setting `self.mapView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`

```
@interface MapViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@end

@implementation MapViewController

    @synthesize mapView = _mapView;
    @synthesize annotations = _annotations;


    -(void)setMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
    {
        _mapView = mapView;
        [self updateMapView];
    }

    -(void)setAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations
    {
        _annotations = annotations;
         [self updateMapView];
    }


    -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
               viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
     // For some reason this method is never called!!!!!!
     NSLog(@"This logging statement is never printed");

   }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.mapView.delegate = self;
    }

    - (void)updateMapView
    {
        if (self.mapView.annotations) [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
        if (self.annotations) [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.annotations];
    }

@end
```

Comment: did you add the function in the .h file?

Comment: Can you amend your question with the implementation of the `updateMapView` method? Can you confirm that you have correctly added the annotations to the map view?

Comment: I've added the updateMapView method. I can confirm the annotations do already appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are forgotten to hook up delegate outlet to files owner. right-click on it and hook up its delegate outlet to File's Owner.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation is that there are no annotations.

Check the code that actually is adding the annotations to the `mapView`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My MapView is definitely rendering the annotations since I can see them on the map. However, whenever I try and override the default view for the annotation using my own implementation of viewForAnnotation(), it gets ignored.

Comment: try to assign the delegate in IB, rather than doing it programmatically

Comment: How do I assign a delegate in Interface Builder? I am using XCode 4.5 with storyboards.

Comment: Ctrl+Click (or right-click) on the map and drag the line to the `File's Owner` object in IB.

Comment: I think this works a bit differently in XCode 4.5 because I can see no File's Owner object in IB.

Comment: In your storyboard, at the bottom of the View Controller there is a Yellow cube. That's the `File's Owner` object.